Custom font-weight definition for non-standards files
I have a non standarnd font file that font weight values are variable from 38 to 682 and any value in this range can be used.
When in css I write font-weight: bold; by default it change to font-weight: 700; and because it is over 682 it is Ultra bold.
Is there any way to tell css that change font-weight: bold; to something like font-weight: 249;? We don't want to use 249 directly in css in case font change later.
This is how font defined:
@font-face {
  font-family: "Font Name";
  src: url("Font-Name-Variable.woff2") format("woff2 supports variations");
  font-weight: 38 682;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}


You could map specific font-weights to a specific weight-axis value by adding a font-variation-settings property to you @font-face rule.
Unfortunately, only Firefox currently supports font-variation-settings in font-face – they are well supported in element style rules (See caniuse record).


@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-stretch: 100%;
  font-variation-settings: "wght" 720;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v28/V8mVoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwrzaFxV7JtdQgFqXdUC4nMm4.woff2) format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-stretch: 100%;
  font-display: swap;
  font-variation-settings: "wght" 150;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/adventpro/v28/V8mVoQfxVT4Dvddr_yOwrzaFxV7JtdQgFqXdUC4nMm4.woff2) format('woff2');
}

body {
  font-family: 'Advent Pro';
  font-size: 2em;
}
<h1>Works only in Firefox</h1>
<p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible <strong>vermin.</strong></p>



The above example maps the regular weight to font-variation-settings: "wght" 720 and bold to "wght" 150.
So to this date you need to write adjust your style rules and add the specific axis values or weights.
strong,
h1, h2, h3{
  font-weight: 249;
  /* or use font-variation-settings*/
  font-variation-settings: "wght" 249;
}


The CSS Fonts Module spec calls out that font-variation-settings low-level mechanism and advises against its use except is special circumstances, particularly in relation to axes for which there is a high-level property defined, such as font-weight. See https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-4/#font-variation-settings-def

@Peter Constable: The main problem here is that we still don't have mature browser API support for variable fonts, and I'm not very optimistic that we'll see major improvements any time soon. However, adding support for font-variation-settings would imho be incredibly helpful for defining desired weights to default values, as we could easily do this with "static" fonts. For example, you could map an axis weight of 500 to the default normal/400 and 800 to bold/700 if a font design tends to have rather thin stems (or the other way round).

@Peter Constable: Regarding the W3C recommendations – I disagree. Sure, it's much more convenient to set a weight for an element style rule using font-weight - but that's another story. For the aforementioned axis-value-to-default mapping, we can't rely on font-weight in a @font-face context (well, we can't really use it in Firefox either =). Also - please correct me - the linked spec section describes ital as a design axis, although there is no such thing as a semi-italic (the interpolatable slnt axis could obviously achieve something like that).

@Peter Constable: All in all, I would only recommend the W3C spec documentation with reservations - also because it doesn't give you any hints about the current state of browser implementations. Sorry for the spec doc ranting – I just can't hide a certain frustration =)

ital is mentioned as a design axis probably because ital is listed in the OpenType design-variation axis tag registry. Note that that says, "The Italic axis can be used as a variation axis within a variable font, though this is not expected to be common." It was necessary to have the ital tag registered so that a font's style relationship within its family could be fully characterized in the STAT table.

When using a variable font, you can specify the integer values as font-weight property values. E.g.,
<p style="font-weight:619;">

See https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-4/#font-weight-prop for specific details.
The font-variation-settings property could also be used, though CSS Fonts Module describes it as a low-level property that isn't meant for general use. One issue with it is that it can be used to set multiple font attributes (variation axes), which are conceptually independent of one another, but any non-default values must be set every time font-variation-settings is used. So, for example, if you were to do this,
div {
  font-variation-settings:"wght" 619;
}
.a {
  font-variation-settings:"wdth" 120;
}

  <div>
    <p>Bold text</p>
    <p class="a">Bold and narrow text?</p>
  </div>

then the second paragraph would use wdth = 120 but wght = 400—the wdth value is not inherited from the div!
If you need to use font-variation-settings, for instance to set values for custom axes in a variable font for which there isn't a CSS property, then CSS variables can be used to work around that limitation. For the above example, the following could be used:
:root {
    --fnt-wght: 400;
    --fnt-wdth: 100;
}

* {
    font-variation-settings: "wght" var(--fnt-wght),
                             "wdth" var(--fnt-wdth);
}

div {
    --fnt-wght: 619;
}

.a {
    --fnt-wdth: 120;
}

In that case, font-variation-settings is set on every element with a value for both wght and wdth axes specified using CSS variables; a default value of the variables is set but each can be overridden for specific elements or classes.
(I need to give credit to Roel Niskens who first wrote about this issue some years ago. See https://pixelambacht.nl/2019/fixing-variable-font-inheritance/.)
But if you're only dealing with variation axes light wght or wdth for which CSS defines properties, then those will get inherited. So, the following works as expected:
div {
  font-weight 619;
}
.a {
  font-width 120;
}

  <div>
    <p>Bold text</p>
    <p class="a">Bold and narrow text?</p>
  </div>

Now the second paragraph will wght = 619, inherited from the div.

Yes, I should probably mention it in question that we don't want to use something like 619 that if font changed we have to change everywhere it used

Could you use a CSS variable instead? Then it needs to be changed only once.

I'll add to my answer.
